# Add LaTex \def to header_includes in RMarkdown YAML

Tags: r, yaml, latex, markdown

I am new at LaTex and i would like to add something like

```
 \def\begincols{\begin{columns}}
```

in the header_includes of my `.Rmd` file. But I don't know how this works.
I can't include it with an external `.tex` file, because of our environ situation. My `.Rmd` looks like:

```
---
output:
  beamer_presentation: 
    keep_tex: true
params:
       dashTitle: NA
header_includes:
- \def}{\begincols}{\begin{columns}}
- \def\begincol{\begin{column}}}
- \def\endcol{\end{column}}}
- \def\endcols{\end{columns}}}
---
```

Comment: Don't do that. If you don't like to type the environments either use an editor that supports good autocomplete or other shortcuts. Alternatively, beamer also supports the syntax `\column` if you don't like the environment, but this is more error prone.

Comment: I just want multiple columns in beamer where I can put my R Chunk in it. Can you give me an advice?

Comment: Rmarkdown has its own syntax for adding columns. Such commands won't help with your frame in frame problem form your previous question. Even if you manually end the previous frame before you start a new one, you will still have the problem, that the r chunk won't be placed in the frame you started and you will end up with the column environment split over multiple frames which of course will cause such an error.

Answer (score 0):

Don't do that! That only obfuscates the code for no gain. Instead of such shortcuts, use an editor that either has good autocompletion or supports shortcuts to insert such environments more easily.

If you insist on macros instead of environments, beamer supports the syntax of `\column` for inserting columns and if you really really must, you can use the underlying tex macros instead of the `columns` environment

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}
    
\begin{frame}
    \begin{columns}[onlytextwidth]
    \column{.5\textwidth}
      something
    \column{.5\textwidth}
      something else  
  \end{columns}
\end{frame} 

\begin{frame}
    \columns[onlytextwidth]
    \column{.5\textwidth}
      something
    \column{.5\textwidth}
      something else  
  \endcolumns
\end{frame} 
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you, but with your macro solution, i get error: `illegal parameter number in definition of \beamer@doifinframe`, when I put R chunk in "somethin"

Comment: @dev123 That's why I said unnecessary code obfuscation won't solve your frame-in-frame problem. Use rmakrdown syntax for columns if you want to use r chunks in them